# Emacs configuration for xml files of FreeBSD Documentation Project

Tags: xml, emacs, freebsd, emacs24, dot-emacs

I'm using Emacs and trying to edit some *.xml files of FreeBSD Documentation Project.
(https://www.freebsd.org/docproj/)

It requires *.xml files to conform following conditions:

- Word wrap set to 70 characters.
- Tab stops set to 2.
- Replace each group of 8 leading spaces with a single tab.

So I added several lines in ~/.emacs as the instruction says:

```lisp
(defun local-sgml-mode-hook
    (setq fill-column 70
      indent-tabs-mode nil
      next-line-add-newlines nil
      standard-indent 4
      sgml-indent-data t)
  (auto-fill-mode t)
  (setq sgml-catalog-files '("/usr/local/share/xml/catalog")))
(add-hook 'psgml-mode-hook
      '(lambda () (local-psgml-mode-hook)))
```

However, it seems not working correctly. When I open *.xml file of FDP in Emacs, sgml-mode is not automatically detected.

I manually enabled this mode via `M-x sgml-mode`.
In this mode, **tab stops set to 2** and **8 leading spaces->single tab** worked fine,
while **word wrap set to 70 chars** seems not working(this means when I exceeded the limit, there isn't any highlight I can recognize).

So the problems are:

1. Not entering sgml-mode automatically
2. Word wrap set to 70 chars doesn't working

I'm using Vim right now, but I prefer Emacs for my text editing.
What should I do to edit files appropriately(make documents conform to FDP guidelines) with Emacs?

Thanks.

p.s. I posted about this on freebsd-doc mailing list and FreeBSD forum, but my problem is not solved--so I'm asking here.

Comment: You seem be to missing the (empty) parameter list, should be `(defun local-sgml-mode-hook ()`, is that just a typo in posting? Or...

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your problem, but it might be worth investingating `nxml-mode` instead of using `sgml-mode` for working with XML. In my opinion it is vastly superior.

Comment: @npostavs I copied that code directly from FreeBSD's suggestion: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/fdp-primer/editor-config-emacs.html

Comment: @hwong: I see. Then it's a typo in FreeBDS's suggestion. I sent an email to the `freebsd-doc` address listed at the bottom.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed this is for *p*sgml-mode, not Emacs' builtin `sgml-mode`. Its [emacswiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PsgmlMode) says you can get a 24.x compatible version from [marmalade](https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/psgml), but since it hasn't really been updated since 2005, @Chris' suggestion of `nxml-mode` is likely a better idea.

Comment: @npostavs Okay, I'm currently looking for configuration in `nxml-mode`. I'll add a comment here as soon as I find proper one. Thanks again!

Comment: `auto-fill-mode` with `nxml-mode` would be close to the answer.